# Disable GNOME's automount with Python

Tags: python, gnome, hal, automount

I need to stop GNOME/Nautilus from automagically mounting new devices and partitions as they appear to the system. How can I accomplish this in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would do it in Python? You can just use the commandline, as in:

```
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/media_automount false
```

If you really need it to be in Python, then you can use the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html):

```
import subprocess

def setAutomount(value):
    """
    @type value: boolean
    """
    cmd = ['gconftool-2', '--type', 'bool', '--set', 
            '/apps/nautilus/preferences/media_automount']
    cmd.append(str(value).lower())
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)

setAutomount(False)
```

But I'm really not sure that it's necessary here.

Comment: You could do something equivalent with the 'gconf' python module, which wraps libgconf, documented here: http://library.gnome.org/devel/gconf/stable/